# Managing Angular 2 state using @ngrx/store with different kinds of views

Tags: angular, redux, immutability, ngrx

I've read a lot of guides and tutorials about Angular 2, immutable state and Redux-like @ngrx/store for managing the application state. I'm really fascinated about it and I plan to use it in my next project. However, I'm new with Angular 2 and with immutable state store, so I have one thing that is puzzling me.

Let's say I have a quite large domain model in the backend. Maybe **Customers**, **Projects**, **People**, **Tasks**, etc. Some of the application views focus on managing the customer side of the application, some focus on totally different objects. In general, not all the views have anything in common with each other.

As all the guides and blog posts say, in @ngrx/store you should have a single object tree holding the application state.

I'm not planning to use WebSockets so I have to reload the state from the backend when navigating between different sections of the app.

How and when should I populate the state from the backend to the frontend? If the user is navigating in the **Customer** section of the app, she doesn't need the **Tasks** at all. Then again, if she navigates to the **Task** part of the app and later navigates back to the **Customer** section, how will the state change between the navigation steps?

Should I have the **Customers** list in the state but clear it when navigating away from that section? Or should I just leave them there and re-populate the store when navigating back?

If I always have the whole application's state object *populated* it feels like I have *too much information* on the client side without a real need for that.

This is not that technical question, but all design ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds from your question that you might confuse the *model* and the *state*. I realize it might be a fine line but state tends to contain transient information such as the currently logged-in user, the state of a menu branch (expanded/collapsed), the values entered so far in a multi-step form, etc. A customers list loaded from the backend doesn't necessarily belong in the state. What makes you think you need to store it in the state? What's wrong with loading it from the backend when you need it and then forget about it when navigating away?

Comment: (If your concern is hitting the backend too often, you might have a *caching issue* more than a *state issue*.)

Comment: Good points. For me it's hard to understand what to actually put to the store. UI state related for sure, but if e.g. a view wants to manipulate certain entities and always after a route change have a fresh set of them from the backend, should I keep them out of the state? All examples seem to just load them once from the backend and then operate with them. That however doesn't work well when a lot of users are operating on the same data. But yeah, @angularFrance said it nicely, backend stuff doesn't necessarily have to be in the state. Thanks for the clarification!